# How to generate OpenAPI schema from Avro Schema

Tags: avro, openapi, openapi-generator

I am looking at openapi-generator to see if I can create an OpenAPI schema from an avro schema using the tool.  Looking at the documentation, I have not been able to figure out how to provide the parameters to be able to do that.  How can I achieve this?

Or, is there another way to get OpenAPI schema from an avro schema either using any online tool or programmatically and how?

The reason I need to do schema to schema conversion is that we use kafka streaming for message transmission and do not have a REST endpoint that could be used with Swagger that would generate the schema. Also, the generated message may not contain all attributes from the avro schema and doesn't identify the optional / mandatory attributes.

Thank you